# How to use External Data Sets in test set

Tags: machine-learning, training

I have a doubt regarding usage of external datasets like gdp rate, unemployment rate... etc., in test set for time series prediction. These datasets are historical and can be used along with train set, but how can it be used along with test set ? Do we need to predict it first and then use it along test set or are there any better ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you should use the same data on your train, test and prediction sets. For economical data this can be tricky :

- In your train set, you need to get what data was available at a given time. This can be tricky because most of the time such economical data can be revised a long time after being first published. For example in my country, I think GDP can be revised up to 3 years after initial publication. Sor for exemple, if you have an instance in 2015 in your train / test set, you need to get what data was available in 2015, not revised numbers that could happen up to 2018.
- In your test set, and for general prediction, the actual value can be an estimation of what is currently happening (nowcasting), so you have to make sure that you data source are consistent. Nowcasting techniques are sometimes used to get the current values (for exemple to get an idea of the activity of the hotel sector you can look at booking.com # of reservation ... etc.). Those techniques are entirely different from what is generaly used to get final numbers (agglomeration of fiscal declarations). Ideally you have to make sure the methods are consistent between, train, test and prediction sets. Using other methods to get data for prediction should not be intirely excluded, but should come with very strong warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Any data can be used in test set if the data has labels.

External data is often used in the test set to see how well the model can generalize to unseen data.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with time series prediction, incorporating external datasets into both the training and testing phases can provide valuable information to improve the model's performance. Here are some common approaches:

1. **Include Historical Values in Training Data:**

   - Include historical values of external features (e.g., GDP rate, unemployment rate) in your training dataset along with the corresponding target variable (the variable you are trying to predict).
   - Train your time series model on this extended dataset, allowing it to learn patterns and relationships between the target variable and external features.
2. **Use Lagged Values of External Features:**

   - Include lagged values of external features in both the training and testing datasets. This means using past values of external features as additional input features for each time step.
   - For example, if you are predicting the target variable for time t, include the values of external features at times t-1, t-2, etc., as additional input features.
3. **Predict External Features for the Test Set:**

   - Train a separate model to predict future values of external features for the test period. This model can be trained on historical data for those features.
   - Use the predicted values of external features as inputs to your time series model during the testing phase.
4. **Rolling Window Approach:**

   - Train your model on a rolling window of historical data, and for each prediction in the test set, retrain the model with additional historical data up to that point.
   - This way, the model continually adapts to the evolving patterns in both the target variable and external features.
5. **Ensemble Models:**

   - Combine predictions from different models. For example, you can have one model that focuses on predicting the target variable and another model that focuses on predicting external features. Combine their predictions to improve overall performance.
6. **Feature Engineering:**

   - Create new features based on the external data that might capture relevant information for predicting the target variable. For example, create a moving average of the GDP rate over a specific period.